# Woher kommt der Dativ in »Wie dem auch sei«?

Tags: grammatical-case, idiom, dative

Ich verstehe nicht, was der Dativ in diesen bekannten Konstrukten zu suchen hat:

> Wie dem auch sei, …
>
> Dem ist nicht so.

Folgende Alternativen ergäben für mich Sinn:

> Wie es auch sein mag, …
>
> Dies ist nicht so.

Diese Ausdrücke werden aber so gut wie nicht gebraucht. Wieso wird hier *dem* verwendet? Ich kann mir nicht vorstellen, dass es mit dem allgemeinen Vormarsch des Dativs begründet werden kann.

Die [Erklärungsversuche](http://forum.pons.eu/de/forum-deutsch-russisch/deutsche-grammatik/wie-dem-auch-sei-t2282.html), die ich bis jetzt gefunden habe, sind ein wenig unbefriedigend. Wer kann mir den Dativ erklären?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Es handelt sich beim Ausdruck *wie dem auch sei* um eine formelhafte Wendung mit konzessiver Bedeutungskomponente. Konzessive Elemente werden im Satz vorangestellt und haben Themafunktion.

Konzessive Angabesätze, auch Einräumungssätze genannt (von lateinisch: concedere = zugestehen), sind besondere adverbiale Nebensätze mit einschränkender Bedeutung. Mit einem konzessiven Nebensatz drückt man einen Gegensatz oder einen unzureichenden Gegengrund zur Aussage des Hauptsatzes aus. Einen solchen Nebensatz leiten zum Beispiel Wörter wie *obwohl*, *obgleich* oder (seltener) *obschon* oder *obzwar* ein.

Hier ein Beispiel für einen "normalen", einleitenden Konzessivsatz:

> Er mag noch so protestieren, er muss doch wie alle anderen warten.

Zur eigentlichen Frage, warum hier Dativ steht. Grammatikalisch gesehen enthält die feste Wendung *wie dem auch sei* folgende Elemente:

1. *dem:* Demonstrativpronomen im Dativ (entspricht *diesem*)
2. *sei:* 3. Person Singular Konjunktiv I des Verbs *sein*

Zu 1: Der Dativ wird hier als alter Komparationskasus (Vergleichsfall) verwendet. *"Dem ist so"* könnte man auflösen zu *"Es ist so wie das (eben Geschilderte)"*. Ich vermute, dass der im Mittelhochdeutschen übliche dativische Ausdruck in festen Wendungen erhalten blieb, da er kürzer (Sprachökonomie) ist.

Zu 2: Normalerweise wird der Konjunktiv im Deutschen nur in der indirekten Rede und bei irrealen Wünschen und Bedingungssätzen verwendet. Allerdings gibt es eben oben erwähnte feste Wendungen, in denen das Verb im Konjunktiv steht. Ein anderes Beispiel findet sich in folgender Zeile des Vater-Unser-Gebets:

> Dein Wille geschehe

oder auch

> Komme, was wolle

Ähnliche feste, formelhafte Wendungen wie *wie dem auch sei* sind u. a.

> *Komme, was da wolle, ...* (oder: *Mag kommen, was da wolle, ...*)
>
> *Sei dem, wie ihm wolle: ...*

Comment: [Komparationskasus](http://de.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20071126130015AADqnBo) also. Danke :)

Comment: Vielleicht kommt das "dem" aus "Wie es auch in diesem / dém (betont) Fall auch sein mag".