# »[…], ist dem nicht so.« – Warum »dem«?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-case

> Obwohl sie meinen, dass es besser ist, ist **dem** nicht so.

Ich würde in diesem Satz *das* benutzen, aber das war falsch. Warum soll man hier *dem* benutzen?

Comment: Zwei ähnliche Fälle: _Wie dem auch sei._ _Wenn dem so wäre..._

Comment: Komparationskasus - http://german.stackexchange.com/a/3036/1224 -  Aber irgendwelche andere Quellen finde ich dazu nicht.